# How to pass slurm arrays as argument in the sbatch command line?

Tags: arrays, r, arguments

I would like to pass as argument the number of arrays I need to execute my R script. I mean, with one array, I can compute 55.000 columns of my file. My file has 820.000 columns, so I need 820.000/55.000~15 arrays. I store this value in a R variable `nb_arrays=ncol(my_file)/55.000` .

I don't want to change my slurm code : what I want to get is a "automatic" `sbatch` command line , which depends of the `nb_arrays` variable.

It would look like this : `sbatch --array 1-nb_arrays my_file.R`

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -o job-%A_task.out
#SBATCH --job-name=paral_cor
#SBATCH --partition=normal
#SBATCH --time=1-00:00:00
#SBATCH --mem=50G  
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=32
#SBATCH --array=1-10

#Set up whatever package we need to run with

module load gcc/8.1.0 openblas/0.3.3 R

# SET UP DIRECTORIES

OUTPUT="$HOME"/PROJET_M2/data/$(date +"%Y%m%d")_parallel_nodes_test
mkdir -p "$OUTPUT"

export FILENAME=/home/PROJET_M2/bin/RHO_COR.R

subset="$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID"

#Run the program

echo "Start job :"`date`

Rscript $FILENAME --subset $subset --file $1 > "$OUTPUT"/"$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID"

echo "Stop job : "`date`
```

Comment: You just need to build a string. In R that's done with `paste0()`. try `mycmd <- paste0("sbatch --array 1-", nb_arrays, " my_file.R")`. Maybe use `round(nb_arrays)` to make sure you get a whole number.

Comment: What I wondered was to modify my slurm code (I edited my post). For example, if I need 10 arrays, to I necessarily  need to change by hand this line  `#SBATCH --array=1-10 ` ? Or is there a way to make the translation between the slurm and the R code thanks to the variable `nb_arrays`?

Comment: Well, if you are running the Rscript code inside a slurm job, there's no way for that R script to change the slurm job properties. Those were already set by `sbatch` and had to be set before the script could run. This doesn't really have anything to do with R in particular. This is just how slurm works.

Comment: Ok, I know what you mean. I wondered that the `SLURM_ARRAYS_TASK_COUNT` variable could help me.

Comment: That can tell you how many were configured for your job so you can read it from R, but you can't change or update it from R.

Comment: Actually, what I just want to get is a "automatic" slurm code. I mean, with one array (=one node) of my cluster, I can compute up to 55.000 correlations of my matrix. My matrix has 820.000 columns, so I need 15 arrays. But if I want to use another file, for example with 550.000 columns, I will need 10 arrays. And that's my problem : I don't want to rewrite my slurm code with #SBATCH --array=1-10 but that the slurm code compute "automatically" the number of arrays needed.. If it is possible?